# Discord.py rewrite have bot respond to DMs

Tags: discord.py, dm

I am trying to have my bot respond to a DM message that accepts the rules.

Here is what I have so far:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  role = discord.utils.get(member.servers.roles, name='Newcomers') #get role
  await bot.add_roles(member, role) #give the role to the user
  await bot.member.send("Welcome to the Moderator Bot Server! I will need you to first read the rules then accept by using the `mbs accept` in this DM")#send a message
  #wait for accept
```

Comment: What is wrong with the program? What do you need help with?

Comment: At a guess, this should be `await member.add_roles(role)` and `await member.send(...)`

Comment: This looks like some old discord.py code from before the rewrite. What discord.py version are you running? If you are running something above 1.0.0 then follow the suggestion from Patrick Haugh.

Comment: @Holden the program works fine, I am just wanting to have the user accept the rules by entering a command. I don't know how to have the bot detect the command in DMs

Comment: @PatrickHaugh please see comment above

Comment: They could type a command or give a reaction to show they accepted the rules, and when they do that, give them the role

Comment: But how do I detect that command @Holden?

Comment: Which discord.py version are you using?  For new versions, use `Client.wait_for`; for old versions use `Client.wait_for_message`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code for your query:

```
role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name='Newcomers') #get role
await member.add_roles(role) #give the role to the user
await member.send("Welcome to the Moderator Bot Server! I will need you to first read the rules then accept by using the `mbs accept` in this DM")#send a message

def check(m):
    return isinstance(m.channel, discord.DMChannel) and m.author == member and m.content == "mbs accept"

await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
#do stuff here; this line runs once the user types `mbs accept` in the DM (maybe you want to send the user a message that thanks them for accepting the rules?)
```

The first 3 lines are what you provided us, although I updated them so they work for discord.py-rewrite (read more on the discord.py rewrite docs [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

#### Check Function

Then, the `check` function first checks if the channel the message was sent in is a DM, it checks if the author is the member, and it checks if the message content is `mbs accept`.

#### Wait For Function

Then, it waits_for the message, using the check we provided. Read more on the `wait_for` function [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for).

*PS:* Sorry for the late response, if you have any unforeseen errors or have questions, feel free to follow up!